# What geometric entity does the 1-norm of a vector imply?

Tags: geometry, normed-spaces

If I constrain a n-dimensional vector $v_n$ to have a 2-norm of $a$, it can be interpreted geometrically to limiting $v_n$ to the space of vectors that touch the shell of a radius $a$ sphere.

$$
v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n \,\,\,\,;\,\,\, ||v_n||_2 = a
$$

If I instead specify that $v_n$ must have a 1-norm of $b$, does this imply the vector $v_n$ must lie on the surface of some other geometric object?

$$
v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n \,\,\,\,;\,\,\, ||v_n||_1 = b
$$

Comment: I apologise if this has already been answered! I looked for this, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $1$-norm sphere is a diamond.

For $2$ dimension, try to connect $(0,b), (-b,0), (0,-b), (b,0)$ using line segments to see the diamond.

when $b=1$.

[image]

Comment: In 3D it is an octahedron, and in higher dimensions, a cross polytope.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer!